# E0289 отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "CType::CType", соответствующие списку аргументов

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

у меня следующая проблема. Когда я пытаюсь воспользоваться конструктором с параметрами, компилятор выдаёт ошибку E0289. Пишет, что отсутствует экземпляр конструктора для float. Конструктор по умолчанию работает, а конструктор с параметрами нет.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CType
{
private:
    float m_Long;
    string m_Brand;
public:
    CType()
    {
        m_Long = 33.5;
        m_Brand = "Airbus";
    }
    CType(float Long, string& Brand)
    {
        m_Long = Long;
        m_Brand = Brand;
    }
    ~CType()
    {
        cout << "CType Destructor worked.\n";
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << m_Long << "\n" << m_Brand << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    CType first(22.5f,"Boing");//ошибка 22.5f
    first.print();
}
```

Comment: `CType(float Long, const string& Brand)` или `CType(float Long, string Brand)`

Comment: Спасибо. В этом была ошибка. Не могли бы Вы объяснить, почему так?

Comment: потому что rvalue нельзя забиндить на lvalue ссылку. На ссылку на константу - можно, по значению - можно.

Comment: некоторые думаю, что "Boing" - это rvalue в данном случае. Нет, это lvalue, Но вот только компилятор на самом деле делает  код вида `CType first(22.5f, std::string("Boing"));` и вот `std::string("Boing")` - это уже rvalue (но не rvalue reference:) )

Comment: @KoVadim я так понимаю вы имеете ввиду, что компилятор сначала создает `std::string` из набора литералов `Boing` и уже сам анонимный объект `std::string` является rvalue. Но разве набор литералов `Boing` не будут также являться rvalue?

Comment: строка в двойных кавычках - lvalue. Вот так. Вот на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/587644/) даже человек пытается выкрутится "А тем, что text имеет адрес в памяти, а выражение "some text" его не имеет, точнее его адрес не так просто найти. Адрес постоянного объекта можно узнать так:" :) В комментариях его пытаются надоумить, но как то не то... Что ещё раз подтверждает мою гипотезу, что move семантику никто толком не понимает:)